# Mock AWS SDK calls from a Node module using Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, aws-sdk

In Node, both my code and a module in the node_modules folder use the AWS SDK. When I mock AWS using the `aws-sdk-client-mock`, my code is correctly mocked when I run my tests, but any calls using the SDK from the module are not mocked. If I copy the code out of the `node_modules` folder and import it directly, it is mocked correctly. Is there a way to ensure that all calls to the SDK are getting mocked even if called from a module?

Here is a sample of test.js file.

```
import { mockClient } from "aws-sdk-client-mock";
import {
    SecretsManagerClient,
    GetSecretValueCommand
} from "@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager";
import {
  RedshiftDataClient,
  ExecuteStatementCommand,
  DescribeStatementCommand,
  GetStatementResultCommand
} from '@aws-sdk/client-redshift-data';
import { SQSClient, SendMessageCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-sqs";
import { SNSClient, PublishCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-sns";

const secretsClient = mockClient(SecretsManagerClient);
const ddbMock = mockClient(RedshiftDataClient);
const SQSMock = mockClient(SQSClient);
const SNSMock = mockClient(SNSClient);

secretsClient.on(GetSecretValueCommand).resolves({SecretString: '{"username": "asdad", "password": "asdas"}'});

beforeEach(() => {
  ddbMock.reset();
  SQSMock.reset();
  SNSMock.reset();
  SQSMock.on(SendMessageCommand).resolves({
    MessageId : "someId"
  });
  SNSMock.on(PublishCommand).resolves({
    MessageId : "someId"
  });
  ddbMock.on(ExecuteStatementCommand).callsFake(input => {
    return Promise.resolve({Id: 'efg'});
  })
  .on(DescribeStatementCommand).callsFake(input => {
    return Promise.resolve({Status : "FINISHED", Id: "efg", HasResultSet: false});
  })
  .on(GetStatementResultCommand).callsFake(input => {
    return Promise.resolve(redshiftResponse);
  });
});

afterEach(jest.clearAllMocks);
```

In this case, the module that is using the SDK accepts JSON, builds the SQL and handles communication with Redshift. I've tried mocking the module instead of the SDK, which does work, but I am unable to validate the final SQL that is going to be sent to AWS. This is a requirement of the project I am working on.